# Display value in canvas during mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Dear JavaScript users,

I need to be able to:

1. load a png image and display it on a canvas
2. store its original pixel values
3. transform the pixel values to represent new colours
4. display the original values on the screen when the user moves their cursor over the image

This may sound like a slightly odd thing to do, but the original pixel values in my live system will contain encoded data that I need to retain, and display on the screen after whatever pixel value manipulation is subsequently carried out. I need to change the colour mapping after the initial loading of the image to make it more pleasing to the eye, but need to display the original values on the screen.

My method works when displaying some simple geometrical shapes on the canvas, but as soon as I try to use a png image it stops working. Can anyone help me to understand why this is?

An example (without the pixel value transformation) that works with the simple shapes is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/1219/

If you comment out lines 24 - 29, and uncomment lines 32 - 40 so that it loads in a png, it stops working. The png file loads, but the data values are no longer shown on the screen.

Any suggestions as to why it breaks when I use a png would be welcome; any suggestions on how to fix it would be even more welcome!

Many thanks in advance for any help.

David

```js
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
    return undefined;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}


var example = document.getElementById('example');
var context = example.getContext('2d');


// The squares works
context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
context.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,255)";
context.fillRect(55, 0, 50, 50);
// End of squares


/*
// Replacing the squares section above with this 
// png image stops the mouseOver from working, Why?
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.width, imageObj.height, 0, 0, imageObj.width*4, imageObj.height*4);
};
imageObj.src = 'http://dplatten.co.uk/mouseOver/skin_dose_map.png';
*/


var originalValues = new Array();
originalValues = context.getImageData(0,0,280,360).data;

$('#example').mousemove(function(e) {
    var pos = findPos(this);
    var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
    var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
    var coord = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
    var c = this.getContext('2d');
    var r = originalValues[(y*280 + x)*4];
    var g = originalValues[(y*280 + x)*4+1];
    var b = originalValues[(y*280 + x)*4+2];
    $('#status').html(coord + "<br>" + r + "," + g + "," + b);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="example" width="280" height="360"></canvas>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is two-fold

First of all, these two line:

```
var originalValues = new Array();
originalValues = context.getImageData(0,0,280,360).data;
```

are being run before you paint the image since it's waiting for the image to load still.

Then, if would move the context.getImageData() to inside the imgObject.onload-function, you'd run into another problem namely, you can't run getImageData() on an image that is not on the same location as the file that is running the script. You will get the following message:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

If you put the image on the same server and move the getImageData() call inside the onload-function, it should work.

Comment: :Eeek: I did a double take when I refreshed the page to see your answer. I had written almost word for word the same thing you did. I'd started out with "The problem you have is two-fold" and then went on to address the same points. Nice work! :)

Comment: Many thanks for the fast response. I'll try it out tomorrow and let you know how I get on. The image will be on the same server on the live version.